# Unfortunately <app-name> has stopped - eclipse device emulater error

Tags: java, android, eclipse

When I try to run my app using the emulator, I get the error the title suggest. Console says everything went smooth and logcat shows nothing. Below is my Android Manifest. signIn is the class that should open when launched.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.LoneLightning.app"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
<activity android:name="com.LoneLightning.app.SignIn"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name="com.LoneLightning.app.MainMenu"
    android:label="MainMenu" >
</activity>
<activity
    android:name="com.LoneLightning.app.LevelOne"
    android:label="LevelOne" >
</activity>
<activity
    android:name="com.LoneLightning.orangedot.Leaderboard"
    android:label="Leaderboard" >
</activity>
</application>
```

SignIn.java incase you're curious

```
    import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.BaseGameActivity;

public class SignIn extends BaseGameActivity
    implements View.OnClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sign_in_layout);
        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);        
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.sign_in_button) {
            // start the asynchronous sign in flow
            beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
        }
        else if (view.getId() == R.id.sign_out_button) {
            // sign out.
            signOut();

            // show sign-in button, hide the sign-out button
            findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSignInFailed() {
        findViewById(R.id.textView1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

    public void onSignInSucceeded() {
        // show sign-out button, hide the sign-in button
        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainMenu.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        // (your code here: update UI, enable functionality that depends on sign in, etc)
    }


}
```

Comment: You haven't given us much to go on. Could you at least post your layout xml? Perhaps you are attempting to reference an id that isn't present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, according to [the docs](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init), you need to:

> import the gms.common.api package and the BaseGameActivity class.

So, if you already have everything necessary installed, you just need to add the following line:

```
import gms.common.api.*;
```

If not, check [this link](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) to get things set up correctly.